# PrePopulate list value based on link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a global issues list for a site, which people from different pages will be able to click a link to it and add their issues.

[image]

What I would like is the dropdown to autopopulate based on the page you came from. So for example if I came from the "risk mgmt" page the dropdown be "risk Mgmt" or if i can from "vendors" page the dropdown automatically set to "dropdown". etc.

Anyone Know how I can use a link to auto populate these fields?

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution will be looking for previous URL with the help of javascript **document.referrer** and build some logic on the form to pre-select the dropdown items.

1. You can edit the New Form page to put a CEWP and insert some javascript.
2. Use JSLink to attach the custom javascript to the "Process Step" field

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: would you have any more details on how to do this?

Comment: but its not a form, its adding stuff to a sharepoint list.

Comment: 1. Edit the New Form page and add Content Editor Webpart
2. Add javascript to it which will check the previous URL
3. Build some logic to know what is the previous page name from the URL you got in step 2
4. Pre-select the dropdown value accordingly

Comment: but i cant add webparts to the page.